# Объясните как работает код

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
    unsigned int a,b=0;
    printf("Number:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while (a!=0) {
          b=b*10+a%10;
          a=a/10;
          }
    printf("Reversed number:%u\n",b);    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

этот код выводит число в обратном порядке,

b=b*10+a%10;
      a=a/10;  объясните пжл  что просиходит в этих двух сторчках.

прога работает все норм выводит но я не совсем понимаю что за вычисления происходят с b если она равна нулю.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&a,b);` - это не ошибка, но это чушь. Также: формат `%d` для `unsigned int`? Для `unsigned int` предназначен формат `%u`. И `int main(void)`, а не `main()`.

Comment: Ну смотрите. `a%10` - это последняя цифра числа `a`. Дальше, `a/10` - это число `a` без последней  цифры. Так как `a=a/10;` убирает последнюю цифру из `a`, `while (a!=0)` значит "пока остались необработанные цифры в `a`".

Comment: HolyBlackCat , то что вы объяснили я понимаю, а вот b = b*10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (a!=0) {
      b=b*10+a%10;
      a=a/10;
}
```

Давайте на примере... `a = 234`

```
                   a          b
                 234          0
b=b*10+a%10;     234      0*10+4 = 4
a=a/10;           23          4
b=b*10+a%10;      23      4*10+3 = 43
a=a/10;            2         43
b=b*10+a%10;       2     43*10+2 = 432
a=a/10;            0        432
```

Все, `a==0`, цикл завершен.

`b=b*10+a%10;` - по сути сдвиг `b` влево на одну цифру и прибавление последней цифры из `a`.

Так вам понятнее?

Comment: я забыл что цикл повторяется пока а не равно 0, Спасибо что объяснили))